# How do I get order information from the woocommerce payment screen?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, woocommerce, checkout

Hi i want to woocommerce checkout page get woocommerce-checkout-review-order-table.

How do I get all the information for that order? The important thing is to be sensitive to situations such as VAT, cargo. I just need information.

Comment: You can"t get any order details in checkout as the order doesn't exist yet. You can get cart and cart item details instead.

Comment: I just want to keep the order information contained in the payment screen in a variable. And I want to print it to an input on the same page. Is there sample code?

Like purchased products and total price. Same as the order table on the checkout page.

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the details of the products you've added into cart on checkout page. Please check if you've added tax(VAT) and shipping (CARGO) class to each product from your WP admin.

[Here](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/setting-up-taxes-in-woocommerce/) you can refer WC tax rate docs and you can see [here](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/setting-up-eu-vat-rates-for-digital-products/#section-5) to assign products a tax classes.

Similarly, you supposed to create and assign shipping zones and it's rates as well. You can find docs for creating shipping zone from [here](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/setting-up-shipping-zones/)

You can find many tutorials to set shipping for your desire requirements however, here is the one for quick reference. [WooCommerce Shipping Methods](https://flexibleshipping.com/woocommerce-shipping-methods/)

Hope this may help you in your requirements!

Be noted you can't get order information before you placed order successfully. I answer you based on understanding that your need information of tax, shipping cost on checkout page.

Comment: I just want to keep the order information contained in the payment screen in a variable. And I want to print it to an input on the same page. Is there sample code?

Like purchased products and total price. Same as the order table on the checkout page.

Comment: please share screenshot or sample URL of the page where you want to access order details. If you're referring the screen after payment, yes! you can access order details using the order_id but please let me share screenshot first.